# How to show once the current status?

Tags: php

I have a database for a homework, which holds hotel reservations.

I have to check for a reservation, based on a date.

for example:

2017-06-14

The query returns the room number, and print out the availability.

```
$selectedDay = $_POST['selectedDay'];
$select_date = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM events WHERE '$selectedDay' BETWEEN start AND end - INTERVAL 1 DAY";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $select_date);
echo "<h2>Free rooms in this date: <br/> $selectedDay</h2>";
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    While ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<h3>" . $row['name'] . "</h3>";
        for ($i = 1; $i < 20; $i++) {
            if ($row['room' . $i] == '1') {
                echo "Room " . $i . ": <span style='color:red;'>busy</span> <br />";
            } else {
                echo "Room " . $i . ": <span style='color:green;'>free/span> <br />";
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "No data for this date.";
}
```

I want ONE overall list of the rooms, now if there is 3 guest in the selected day, the list will be printed 3 times.

picture of the table:
https://ibb.co/jBVcik

Comment: You need to restructure your DB-design. Have one table with the rooms `id, room`. Then have one table for the guests: `id, name, email, etc...`. Then you can have a third table connecting the guests with the rooms. Let's call it bookings: `id, guest_id, room_id, check_in, check_out`. Now you can easily get all kinds of lists using some simple joins.

Comment: and with this table? its not possible?

Comment: You _can_ if you iterate through the results and restructures the data in PHP. Since it is for homework, try to learn and to do it properly from the start instead. No point of learning a lesser way. :-)

Comment: i know, but this is the given table, and we have to do the query in this table..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have found your own solution by now. Just in case you are still inetested in a solution that already does the work in the SQL-query, have a look at this:

```
SELECT group_concat(name) names, count(CASE room1 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r1, count(CASE room2 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r2, 
  count(CASE room3 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r3, count(CASE room4 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r4, count(CASE room5 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r5,
  count(CASE room6 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r6, count(CASE room7 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r7, count(CASE room8 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r8,
  count(CASE room9 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r9, count(CASE room10 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r10,count(CASE room11 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r11,
  count(CASE room12 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r12, count(CASE room13 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r13, count(CASE room14 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r14
FROM tbl where '20170823' between start and enddt-interval 1 day
```

It results in something like this

```
names               r1  r2  r3  r4  r5  r6  r7  r8  r9  r10 r11 r12 r13 r14
Charlie,Sally,Patty 0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

You can play around with it here: http://rextester.com/HNDA58846

(I used the MySQL specific function `group_concat()` to also show the names of all guests present on the chosen date.)

If you want to end up with a table of results (for a sequence of reservation dates) you could change it slightly to

```
SELECT dt,
   group_concat(name) names, count(CASE room1 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r1, count(CASE room2 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r2, 
   count(CASE room3 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r3, count(CASE room4 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r4, count(CASE room5 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r5,
   count(CASE room6 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r6, count(CASE room7 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r7, count(CASE room8 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r8,
   count(CASE room9 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r9, count(CASE room10 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r10,count(CASE room11 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r11,
   count(CASE room12 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r12, count(CASE room13 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r13, count(CASE room14 WHEN '1' THEN 1 END) r14
 FROM tbl 
 INNER JOIN (SELECT '20170823' dt UNION ALL SELECT '20170824' UNION ALL SELECT '20170825') dates
  ON dt between start and enddt-interval 1 day
 GROUP BY dt
```

The `WHERE` clause changed into an `ON` clause of a subquery and `dt` is now pulled from that joined subquery (or another table if you so wish). Result:

```
dt          names               r1  r2  r3  r4  r5  r6  r7  r8  r9  r10 r11 r12 r13 r14
20170823    Sally,Charlie,Patty 0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20170824    Sally,Charlie,Patty 0   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20170825    Sally,Patty         0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

If you happen to have a tally table in your database, a simple table with consecutive numbers like this:

```
id
---
 1
 2
 3
 4
 .
..
50
```

you could do an `INNER JOIN` with it to get all dates when somebody actually *is* in one of your rooms:

```
...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CAST('20170801' as date)+ interval id day dt FROM tally) dates
...
```

or a `RIGHT JOIN` if you want to get an overview over a certain date range with *all* the rooms in it (empty or not).